# I'm using the Python logging in two projects. When importing one into the other, only one logger works

Tags: python, logging

I use logging in two projects. Logging works great in each independently. When I import "B" into "A" only "B" logs. I have a "logger_settings.py" file for each project with different output locations and filenames. Am I missing a setting that will allow me to have both projects output their log files?

Both project logger settings file looks like the following with the exception of filename and location is different:

```
logging_config = dict(
    version=1,
    formatters={
        'verbose': {
            'format': ("[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s "
                       "[%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s"),
            'datefmt': "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S",
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s',
        },
    },
    handlers={
        'api-logger': {'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                           'formatter': 'verbose',
                           'level': logging.DEBUG,
                           'filename': '../logs/api.log',
                           'maxBytes': 1048576,
                           'backupCount': 4},
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'simple',
            'stream': sys.stdout,
        },
    },
    loggers={
        'api_logger': {
            'handlers': ['api-logger', 'console'],
            'level': logging.DEBUG
        }
    }
)

dictConfig(logging_config)

api_logger = logging.getLogger('api_logger')
```

Projects when they are tested independently write to the logs well. When one is imported into the other, only the imported file will log. I expected both to write to their own log file.

I do not receive any errors.

Comment: That sounds like an imported module replacing names (maybe settings) in the other one.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this problem. To reiterate, I have two python projects. I pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/ one into the other and only the installed logger works.

To allow both of them to log properly, it turned out to be a simple addition to my logger dict:

disable_existing_loggers= False

...and whola!Works like magic... both loggers work nicely